# Count the number of occurrences in a string. Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Okay so what I am trying to figure out is how do I count the number of periods in a string and then cut everything up to that point but minus 2. Meaning like this:

```
string="aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com"

number_of_periods="5"

number_of_periods=`expr $number_of_periods-2`

string=`echo $string | cut -d"." -f$number_of_periods`

echo $string

result: "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd"
```

The way that I was thinking of doing it was sending the string to a text file and then just greping for the number of times like this:

```
 grep -c "." infile
```

The reason I don't want to do that is because I want to avoid creating another text file for I do not have permission to do so. It would also be simpler for the code I am trying to build right now.

**EDIT**

I don't think I made it clear but I want to make finding the number of periods more dynamic because the address I will be looking at will change as the script moves forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to *count* the dots, but just remove the penultimate dot and everything afterwards, you can use Bash's built-in [string manuipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

> `${string%substring}`
>      Deletes shortest match of `$substring` from *back* of `$string`.

Example:

```
$ string="aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com"
$ echo ${string%.*.*} 
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

Nice and simple and no need for `sed`, `awk` or `cut`!

Comment: pretty neat, I didn't know about this (I use `tcsh`, and this unfortunately won't work with it, hence my more universal `awk` approach) - not a problem for OP of course since it's tagged as `bash`. Very nice.

Comment: @Levon: I [avoid scripting (t)csh](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt) when I can. If I had to, I'd use **`sed`**: `echo "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com" | sed 's/\(.[^.]*\)\{2\}$//'`

Comment: @Levon: `echo "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com" | sed 's/.[^.]*.[^.]*$//'` Is even shorter :-)

Comment: Most of the shell scripts I run are `bash`. If I have to write a more complex script that requires flow control/loops etc, I fall back on Python, or just combine awk/sed/grep/uniq etc ..

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
echo "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{NF=NF-2}1'
```

(further shortened by helpful comment from @steve)

gives:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
```

The `awk` command:

```
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{NF=NF-2}1'
```

works by separating the input line into fields (`FS`) by `.`, then joining them as output (`OFS`) with `.`, but the number of fields (`NF`) has been reduced by 2. The final `1` in the command is responsible for the print.

This will reduce a given input line by eliminating the last two period separated items.

This approach is "*shell-agnostic*" :)

Comment: +1 This is my fav solution, because what if the number of fields is very large? Also, you can shorten some more: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="."}{NF=NF-2}1'`

Comment: @steve .. thanks .. I'll update my answer if you don't mind with these tweaks .. I've used them one time or another, but for some reasons they didn't occur to me as I was putting this together iterativley (and slowly :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
#!/bin/sh

input="aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com"

number_of_fields=$(echo $input | tr "." "\n" | wc -l)
interesting_fields=$(($number_of_fields-2))

echo $input | cut -d. -f-${interesting_fields}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o "\." <<<"aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.google.com" | wc -l
5
```